# Not able to establish a connection with Amazon DynamoDB service from javascript

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a web application which tries to connect to amazon DynamoDB. I am successfully able to login to web using "Login with Amazon" service. After that, the application actually attempts to connect to DynamoDB but, shows error "connection refused". I have created a table in DynamoDB service and also created a role attaching a policy to allow access to DynamoDB.

Not sure what exactly I am missing.

Your help is much appreciated. 
The following two snippets are from app.js

```
.constant('configAWS', {
    tableName: "DynTable",
    bucketName: "qqqqq.com",
    region: "US East (N.Virginia)"
})  

.constant('configLogger', {
    amazonAppId:'amzn1.application.xxxxx',
    amazonRoleArn: 'arn:aws:iam::yyyyyy:role/PRole',
    amazonRoleName: "PRole",
});
```

The following code is in services.js

```
baseFactory.handler =  new AWS.DynamoDB({TableName: 'finance',region: 'US East (N. Virginia)', accessKeyId: '...', secretAccessKey: '...'});
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't you need a region that looks like `us-east-1` rather than `US East (N.Virginia)`?

Comment: I changed as you suggested and it appears that the control proceeds further but throws errror as `AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:iam::xxxx:user/pbhat is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:Query on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:xxx:table/finance/index/timestamp`

Comment: That's an IAM permissions error. Does your IAM user have permission to Query on that index?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I came to know that I had not hash key name should be the same as what we mention while creating table in the DynamoDB. Now, it works for me.